# How do I use implode() to insert multiple integers into IN statement using prepared statements in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, implode

**Context**

I have a feed system where users can follow other users on my site and see their posted content, such as threads they created. To accomplish this, I use AJAX to send an array with all the user IDs of the people that the user follows to be queried in an SQL statement (my DBMS is MySQL). In PHP, I then try to take this array and place it in my SQL query using an `IN` statement. In this specific situation, the user follows two other people with the IDs of 11 and 12. So after sending this data to the PHP code via AJAX, I can use `print_r($_POST['following'])` and get this result:

```
Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 12 )
```

To use this in my SQL query, I use the following code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$q = "SELECT forums.forum_id, forums.forum_title, forums.message, 
forums.idUsers, forums.box_id, forums.date, 
forums.seen, users.uidUsers, profileimages.image 
FROM forums 
JOIN users 
JOIN profileimages 
ON forums.idUsers = users.idUsers 
AND profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
WHERE forums.idUsers 
IN (?) //code in question
ORDER BY forums.forum_id DESC 
LIMIT 5 
OFFSET ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $q);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $followingArray, $offset);

$following = $_POST['following'];
$followingArray = implode(", ", $following); //code in question
$offset = $_POST['offset'];

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

After executing the query, I obtain the information and send it back to the server. When I do it this way, there are five returned rows:

```
[{idUsers: 11, forumId: 11, seen: "false", forumTitle: "sixth random thread",…},…]
0: {idUsers: 11, forumId: 11, seen: "false", forumTitle: "sixth random thread",…}
1: {idUsers: 11, forumId: 10, seen: "false", forumTitle: "fifth random thread",…}
2: {idUsers: 11, forumId: 9, seen: "false", forumTitle: "fourth random thread",…}
3: {idUsers: 11, forumId: 8, seen: "false", forumTitle: "third random thread",…}
4: {idUsers: 11, forumId: 7, seen: "false", forumTitle: "second random thread",…}
```

This is good, except for the fact that this ONLY considers posts that involve the user ID of 11, not both 11 and 12. If the `IN` statement included the posts of the user with an ID of 12, then the results would be different. After going directly into the database and querying again after inputting the values manually, like so:

```
SELECT forums.forum_id, forums.forum_title, forums.message, 
forums.idUsers, forums.box_id, forums.date, 
forums.seen, users.uidUsers, profileimages.image 
FROM forums 
JOIN users 
JOIN profileimages 
ON forums.idUsers = users.idUsers 
AND profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
WHERE forums.idUsers IN ('11', '12') 
ORDER BY forums.forum_id DESC 
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

You find that the resulting rows were different; the first result was a post from the user with the user ID of 12.

```
[,…]
[{idUsers: "12", forumId: "12", seen: "false", forumTitle: "first new content here",…},…]
0: {idUsers: "12", forumId: "12", seen: "false", forumTitle: "first new content here",…}
1: {idUsers: "11", forumId: "11", seen: "false", forumTitle: "sixth random thread",…}
2: {idUsers: "11", forumId: "10", seen: "false", forumTitle: "fifth random thread",…}
3: {idUsers: "11", forumId: "9", seen: "false", forumTitle: "fourth random thread",…}
4: {idUsers: "11", forumId: "8", seen: "false", forumTitle: "third random thread",…}
```

This leads me to believe that my `implode()` implementation with the prepared statement is incorrect.

**Question**

Is there something I should be changing with the `implode()` function, such as putting quotes around each value in the array, to make it work with the `IN` statement in MySQL?

**Things I Have Tried**

Believing that my `implode()` function was incorrectly formatted, I tried changing the `$followingArray` variable from `$followingArray = implode("', '", $following);` to `$followingArray = "'" . implode("', '", $following) . "'";`, which simply returned 0 rows. How can I format my `implode()` function to work when trying to insert multiple values into an SQL statement?

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the info - I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NEVER mess with quotes yourself because it leads to a risk of sql injection.

Moreover, in this particular example, you are inserting numbers, but it won't work in the general case if you want to insert a string like "O'Connor" and not even talking about if you want to store an arbitrary text containing both `'` and `"` : the prepared statement takes care of it all, security and quote spaghetti.

My advice is to first `count` the number of id you will be querying upon and add that many `?` in your `IN` clause like this

```
$idCount = //count ids
$questmarks = array_fill(0, $idCount, "?");
$sql .= "IN(".implode(",", $questmarks).")";
```

if you have, say, 5 ids to query, the prepared SQL string will looks like this :

```
SELECT ...
WHERE 
AND id IN (?,?,?,?,?)
LIMIT ?
```

and then bind all your params in order.

```
$params = [$id1,$id2,$id3,$id4,$id5,$offset];

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", ...$params);
```

Comment: I don't think you can bind $offset this way

Comment: You can bind any "?" you want !

Comment: Oh, maybe it's a limitation of the PDO execute() function I'm thinking of

Comment: @smwhr I see the logic, but I'm confused about the syntax. Where would you place the $sql variable? Would it be after the $q variable in my case? ($q =  {SQL statement here}, then $q .= IN(".implode(",", $questmarks).")";) and then place the $q in the mysqli_stmt_bind_param() function?

Comment: @smwhr Ok - just figured out what you meant. I got that part down. Now how do I execute the `$params` section? How do I know how many `$id` variables there should be? Do I set `$params` equal to the array that I receive from the AJAX call?

Comment: Exactly like you said, you're getting it ! In my example, I use the `...` operator that transforms an array into a succession of parameters. But you could do it the way that feels more comfortable to you.

Comment: @smwhr Okay. I used a `foreach` loop to put the ids in the `$params` array and then added the `$offset` into the array as well. I also used `str_repeat` to find how many integers the array had and placed that in the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` function. It works well! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this, based on answered from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/25461349/9661872
`$followingArray = "'" . implode("','", $following) . "'";`